# Should I put a Bard's ability score increases all in Cha or spread them out?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-advancement

This is my first Pathfinder campaign and I was wondering how one would spread their additional ability points they get while leveling. I usually play straight caster or melee but the bard seems to be a lot more versatile and I don't know if I should put all my points in Charisma or spread them out a bit more. I should point out that I was going for a buff build with a ranged focus.

My scores are

Str 13
Dex 18
Con 15
Int 15
Cha 19
Wis 13

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Odd scores are worthless to you, since you’re primarily interested in your modifier (which halves the number and drops the fraction), and just about all bonuses to ability scores come in even numbers. So you’ll get the most *immediate* bang for your buck by upping the odd scores to the next (even) number. So +1 Cha, +1 Con, +1 Str, +1 Wis, probably in that order, would take you to level 16. At level 20, the last one would probably go into Charisma; at those levels you can get an odd bonus to ability scores using *wish* or the associated tomes/manuals.

This has nothing to do with bard, aside from how we order them, it’s just a reaction to the very awkward situation where you have so many odd ability scores. You also have **very** *good* scores, which makes improving secondary and tertiary scores much less important than it usually is.

To address bard specifically, it helps to choose a focus. Making an attack-bard takes different equipment and feats than a caster bard. Even within the “attack-bard” sphere, melee and range are very different. Part of the bard’s strength *is* being a solid jack-of-all-trades, and he is that, but your feats and equipment tend to work better if you focus; the aspects that you focus less on, you’re relying on the solid bard chassis to keep you competent in. So if you focus on spellcasting, your feats and items are mainly geared towards those, but you’re a far better fighter than a wizard is<sup>1</sup> just because of the things that bard automatically gives you.

Unfortunately, Pathfinder has pretty significantly nerfed the bard (disadvantageous changes to bardic music, loss of options available in 3.5 supplements), but [my discussion of the 3.5 bard’s options](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/18691/4563) may nonetheless be useful to you.

<sup>1</sup> In theory, and in practice if the wizard ignores mundane fighting. In reality, with a little effort, the wizard can be better at it than a bard. The wizard can be better than almost anyone at almost anything with a little effort, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks, It has been a real eyeopener as far as how I should move forward. This is my first bard and with my previous experiences I was able to be a bit linear where as I feel that if I did do that with the Bard I would be seriously gimping myself and my party.

Comment: +1. Is there any specific reason you recommend bumping str before wis? at level 16, is a potential +1 dmg better than +1 will save when tons of save or suck spells are available to the enemies?

Comment: @ColinD Will is a good save for the bard, his Wisdom is already pretty solid, and I assume he'll grab the largest resistance bonus to saves he can afford. His Will will hardly be impregnable, but I'm not sure that +1 is worth a whole lot there. Strength, on the other hand, gives attack and damage, and since the bard only has 3/4 BAB, maintaining a decent bonus seemed like a higher priority. But a ranged or finesse or caster bard might very well not care and take Wis first, you're right.

Comment: The only thing I can think of to improve this answer is that 'A bard needs to pick something and focus on it' needs to be *first* in the answer, as the theorycrafting of the bonus to scores, while useful, implies all scores are useful to a bard - or even to all bards.  Bards need, depending on type of bard, str or dex or cha + usually cha regardless.  Wisdom, Intelligence, Con, shouldn't necessarily be dumped but neither should precious level up points be spent in them.

Comment: I'd just add, that you could flesh out the odd scores with inherent tomes, if you want to focus on one ability score. Though those are relatively expensive

Comment: @JackLesnie "Precious"? They're *rare*, but they're also *really small*. Bumping up a less-important modifier now seems more important here than bumping up a more-important modifier in *4 levels*.

Comment: @Andy Massively expensive; putting one of your level-up points in an unimportant score like Str or Wis makes sense; spending that much gold on it, much less so.

Comment: +1 to something you are already good at (save DCs, cha based skill checks, extra spells per day) is usually more useful than +1 to something you don't use often (str on a caster bard, wis on any single-classed bard).  Players and characters will try to do stuff they are good at and avoid stuff they are bad at.  I find people thinking they should be 'all around' characters instead of specializing is the no. 1 sources of player discontent with mechanics in my games.

Comment: It's so useful that two +1's to stuff you don't use much (two level ups into odd ability scores) is probably, in my opinion, worth a lot less than a single +1 to something you use *all the time*, like cha (two level ups on an even ability score).

Comment: @JackLesnie If you're starting that high, I'd probably agree, but to actually level-up through those four levels, particularly when a lot of games don't actually *last* that long.... I wouldn't

Comment: Well, sure, for a game that won't see level 8.  But.. is that the default assumption?  Or should it be, in an answer?

Comment: @JackLesnie The first +1 is to Cha no matter what, so we're talking about hitting 8 but not hitting 12. And I'm saying even if it will (or is supposed to) hit 12, if I'm 8 now, going through 8, 9, 10, and 11 with no benefit when I could have a bump that could mean something to me, I'd probably take it.