# Ring of the Ram and (Any) Golem 3.5 D&D

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Golems, pretty terrifying in their own right (and, I've heard, broken in design), are immune to any spells or spell-like abilities that allow spell resistance and have DR 5-15 / adamantine (and crushing for Clay).

First Question:
Does a Ring of the Ram's damage (Xd6 Force damage for X charges spent, where X is a max of 3) hurt it? As far as I can tell the ring does not allow spell resistance, and since it's magic it bypasses DR, but it seems so *wrong* that such a simple item can hurt a CR 13 Iron Golem.

Second Question:
One of my PCs, a sorcerer, cast Ice Storm. Ice Storm deals part bludgeoning damage and part ice damage. Since *all* of the damage is created magically I assume that *none* of the damage bypasses a Golem's immunity to magic, even though the bludgeoning damage is "mundane" (i.e. a heavy thing hit it on the head.)

P.S. I may stop using Golems in the future.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### *Ring of the Ram*

Spell resistance is defined as affecting spells and spell-like abilities. Some items (wands, command-word items) replicate spells, and are affected by it, but other items are their own magical effect, not replicating a spell, and thus ignore it. *Ring of the ram* does not replicate any given spell, and therefore ignores SR.

As for it being “wrong,” the rules aren’t ever perfect. There are far more egregious oddities than this; in this case there are even SR: No spells that deal force damage, so that much isn’t *so* unusual. Not to mention that Supernatural abilities ignore spell resistance as well, even if they replicate a spell. Spell resistance really *is* about **spells** specifically, not just any kind of magic.

Also, while *ring of the ram* might be “just” an item, 3d6 damage isn’t at all impressive. It’s a ranged attack (not a touch attack), you are limited to 50 charges, and it’s quite pricey.

#### *Ice Storm*

The spell is SR: Yes, and therefore golems are immune to it. That includes both bludgeoning and cold damage.

To affect a golem as a spellcaster, you need SR: No spells, or you need to not affect it directly, but rather indirectly by buffing allies. Conjuration and Transmutation are by far your best bets for these. For a well-prepared spellcaster, golems are usually a fairly minor threat, as it turns out. Spell resistance is common enough that every spellcaster should prepare at least a few SR: No spells every day, and therefore be well-equipped to handle golems. [*Grease*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/17191/4563) does hilarious things to them, for example, and that’s a first-level spell.

Comment: +1 just for mentioning *Grease*. You might want to link your [excellent answer](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/17191/5746) about why *Grease* is great :)