# What are some feats that are required to maximize eldritch blast damage output?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, warlock, eldritch-invocations

I am working on a warlock build for my next campaign and I am having trouble finding feats that would apply and boost Warlock's eldritch blast damage output. This is because Warlock is not a traditional spell caster from PHB and I am unsure which feats would apply to EB as its a ranged touch attack. What are some of my options for EB feats and at what level they would come into play?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the single feat that amplifies the damage of *eldritch blast* the most is **Eldritch Claws** from *Dragon* vol. 358. That gives you a pair of claw attacks that deal damage equal to your unarmed strike + your *eldritch blast*, so you get to apply your *eldritch blast* damage twice in that situation. You can increase this by using **Rapidstrike** and **Improved Rapidstrike** from *Draconomicon*, which would get you four and then six attacks. Alternatively **Beast Strike** from *Dragon* vol. 355 would let your unarmed strike damage include your claw damage (which means your unarmed strikes would do unarmed strike damage + unarmed strike damage + *eldritch blast* damage, so doubling your unarmed strike damage). Since these are just regular unarmed strikes, you can perform a regular attack routine with them, and benefit from anything that gives bonus attacks or whatever.

A clawlock is a very specific build, though, and has some serious trade-offs—you’re melee, you’re making non-touch attacks, and so on. You need a bunch of feats just to make it work at all. It’s not compatible with eldritch essences or blast shapes. And on top of that, *eldritch glaive* from *Dragon Magic* is a blast shape, so you can take that as one invocation and get up to four attacks with *eldritch blast* damage, and it’s at reach and it’s a touch attack, so that starts to make Eldritch Claws look pretty poor in comparison (it is much harder to optimize *eldritch glaive* though, so with the enough investment Eldritch Claws is far superior).

Another sort of oblique feat that will do more to improve your *eldritch blast* damage more than any other is, arguably, **Shape Soulmeld** (*strongheart vest*) from *Magic of Incarnum*. The *strongheart vest* gives you “Constitution ability damage reduction” 1, that is, any Constitution damage dealt to you is reduced by 1. This is relevant because the hellfire warlock’s *hellfire blast* deals 1 Constitution damage to you when you use it, and *hellfire blast* adds up to +6d6 damage to *eldritch blast* (*Fiendish Codex II*). The rules for *hellfire blast* says it doesn’t work if you’re immune to Constitution damge, but *strongheart vest* doesn’t make you **immune**, it just reduces the damage by 1 (which happens to be enough to be safe with *hellfire blast*). RAW, it works, realistically, check with your DM first. (If it doesn’t, the other solution is to dip a level of binder from *Tome of Magic* for Naberius, who gives you ability damage fast healing to heal the damage up immediately.)

For more direct feat-based improvements to *eldritch blast* damage, **Quicken Spell-like Ability** (*Monster Manual*) and **Maximize Spell-like Ability** (*Complete Arcane*) are both potent, but limited in usage, since each can only be used 3 times per day. Note that *eldritch blast* counts as a 1st-level spell, per the *Complete Arcane* errata, which allows you to take these at the earliest-possible level.

For more direct “add some damage to your *eldritch blast*” effects, remember that as a “weapon-like spell,” you can use various options for ranged attacks. Your best single-feat option is **Mortalbane** from *Book of Vile Darkness*, which will add +2d6 damage to your *eldritch blast* 5 times per day. It doesn’t work on Constructs, Outsiders, or Undead, but still, that’s a lot of potential targets.

But with three feats (which is a **ton** but nonetheless), you could take **Martial Study** (something from Shadow Hand), **Martial Stance** (*assassin’s stance*), and **Craven**. Martial Study and Martial Stance are from *Tome of Battle* and allow you to pick up the maneuvers from that book without having levels in those classes, and *assassin’s stance* gives you +2d6 sneak attack damage. No 5/day limitation like Mortalbane, but the targeting restrictions are worse and you have to deny the target Dex to AC somehow, which is a pain. Craven is from *Champions of Ruin*, and adds your character level in extra damage to sneak attack, so your +2d6 becomes +2d6+level, which is pretty good. However, Craven has a massive drawback in that you are not allow fear immunity while using the feat, which also precludes mind-affecting immunity. At low-to-mid levels, it doesn’t matter since you can’t get those things anyway, but at mid-to-high levels they become available and then near-mandatory, which makes Craven very painful at that point. Still, there are some levels at which *assassin’s stance* and Craven are going to be the largest damage boost you can find.

Beyond that, the only other feats that are decent sources of direct improvements to *eldritch blast* damage are **Psionic Shot** and **Greater Psionic Shot** from *Expanded Psionics Handbook* (or [here](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/psionicFeats.htm#psionicShot)). Those will add +2d6 or +4d6 damage, respectively, but you need to be psionic (which might require the **Wild Talent** feat), and then you can only do it once per encounter, effectively, unless you take **Psionic Meditation** (which painfully requires Wis 13).

Comment: Your answer is very comprehensive, but you didn't mention the whole "weaponlike spell" deal, which allows you to take ranged combat feats with eldritch blast, Point Blank Shot and Improved Critical for example, may not be optimal choices, but would also increase the damage output.

Comment: I wonder if there is any equivalent in 5e?

Comment: @yopilapi Correct, I didn’t mention those because they are bad. Point-Blank Shot is only worth taking for Precise Shot (but a *rod of magical precision* is far superior), and Improved Critical simply isn’t worth taking unless you’re starting with an 18-20 threat range (and even then...). The overall point about ranged feats is very true, though; I should at least mention sneak attack and Craven.

Comment: @Pureferret Not for any of these feats. I don’t know 5e that well, so I don’t know what options there are, but I know these haven’t shown up, and aside from *maybe* the psionic ones, probably won’t.

Comment: A simple grease spell or effect denies DEX to AC, in most cases. Takes up an action, but can be an effective combo.

Comment: @nijineko “An action” is just about the most valuable thing in the game, and *grease* has distinct limitations (most notably, in this case, the fact that the target can easily leave the *grease* before the warlock gets a chance to *eldritch blast* if the warlock is the source of *grease*). I know [very well how good *grease* is](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/17191/4563), but it’s a decidedly-non-trivial option for a sneak attacker. Now, an **ally**’s *grease*, that is pretty good, but it depends what the party is doing.

Comment: Another point in favor of Naberius versus the strongheart vest is that, in addition to being unambiguously RAW-legal, stealing the power of hell by using a loophole to avoid the cost is *entirely* in-character for a binder of Naberius.

Answer (score 3):

I know your question is for feats, but also be sure you look at items:

- Gloves of Eldritch Admixture (*Magic Item Compendium*) for extra elemental damage each day based on renewing charges
- Chasuble of Fell Power (lesser and greater varieties) (*Complete Arcane*) for +1/2d6 extra damage
- Belt of Battle (*Magic Item Compendium*) for an extra standard or full action, once per day

I wanted to add, regarding the Chasubles of Fell Power, that the lesser and greater varieties are both priced according to a +1/+2 weapons. It would not be unreasonable to ask your DM to let you build new magic items equivalent to +3/+4/+5 that would grant +3/4/5d6 damage on your *Eldritch Blast* attacks, especially since Warlocks are second only to Artificers at building magic items.